# Create new data frame from existing data

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and am stuck on this issue. I have created a column for customers ages. I have 1000 customers. I need to create a new data frame named Call that includes only those customers whose age is 25 or greater.

Columns

1. ID - 1,2,3,4,5,....
2. Gender - M, F
3. Married - Y, N
4. Income - #
5. Age = #

I started of with using if/else. When I used it I got a new column for each row telling me if it was true, greater then 25, or false, less then 25.

Comment: Please read about [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of `dput(<your data frame>)` into your post or `dput(head(<your data frame>))` if you have a large data frame. Also include code you have tried, any relevant errors, and expected output. If you cannot post your data, then post code for creating representative data. [Do not post images of code and/or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6382434).

Comment: This is pseudo code since you have not provided a reproducible example: `df[df$age >=25,]` (the comma is not a typo). Alternatively, you could do `subset(df, subset = age >= 25)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subset`. Assume your data is called `df`, then you can do:

```
New_df <- subset(df, Age >= 25)
```